# Unable to see all the user input values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am automating my stuff, for which I got stuck at a point.
Anyways explaining it, I am using  user inputs for which some formula is working in the corresponding cell for outputs.However when am looking at the final output it is reflecting only the last input values for the loop.

I wanted to have the final output with all the values submitted.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx',worksheet='sheet1')

loops = int(input("Total Outage in Month: "))
inputs = []
for x in range(loops):
    user_input1 = [input('Enter the Impacted_Device : ') ]
    user_input2 = [input('Number_of_Impacted_Connection :') ]
    user_input3 = [input('Outage_Minutes  :')]

    inputs.append(user_input1)
    inputs.append(user_input2)
    inputs.append(user_input3)
    break


Impacted_Device = input(str("Enter the Impacted_Device : "))
Number_of_Impacted_Connection = int(input("Number_of_Impacted_Connection : "))
Outage_Minutes = int(input("Outage_Minutes : "))
Connection_Outage = int(Number_of_Impacted_Connection * Outage_Minutes)


df1['Impacted Connections'] = np.where((df1['Router'].str.contains(Impacted_Device)== True),Number_of_Impacted_Connection,'None')
df1['Outage Minutes'] = np.where((df1['Router'].str.contains(Impacted_Device)== True),Outage_Minutes,'None')
df1['Connection Outage'] = np.where((df1['Router'].str.contains(Impacted_Device)== True),Connection_Outage,'None')

df1
```

Comment: if you are talking about the for x in range(loops): then there is "break" statement at the end, which will for loop  exit at the very first time. ie. irrespective of  the value of loops variable(considering it to be atleast 1).

Comment: okay,got it. Thanks @ katamit.